# Mule doc name missing

Tags: mule, mule-studio, mule-component, mulesoft, mule-esb

Need small help.  I am using Mule studio 6.5.0.  When I build mule project then for all sub flows in respective .xml file (example : test123.xml), doc:name  is missing.   But in our Git repository for all sub flows  doc:name there.  Attached screenshot here.   .  Could you please suggest ?[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/L5gDb.jpg)

Answer (score 0):

It could be related to an issue fixed in [Studio 6.6.5](https://docs.mulesoft.com/release-notes/studio/anypoint-studio-6.6-with-3.9.4-runtime-update-site-5-release-notes#solved-issues). You should update to the last version anyway, it has many bugfixes and improvements.

Comment: Ok and thanks...    And I have a question   in Munit test case how to  call  salesfoce adapter which is in sub-flow and which is in other flow ?   Could you please help to share sample code accordingly I will write in my code ?

Comment: Please post a new question.